# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-map, array-reduce

I have that code where i want to multiply corp_resp for corp_resp_template and sum dynamically.

```
$total = (array_reduce((array_map(function($x, $y) { return $x * $y; },
                   $corp_resp, $corp_resp_template)),function($carry,$item){return $carry+=$item;},0));
echo $total;
```

Code:

```
 $valor[] = array();
   foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ){

       $valor[] = $value;
```

corp_resp Output:

```
array(17) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> string(4) "0.00" [2]=> string(4) "0.00" [3]=> string(4) "0.00" [4]=> string(4) "0.00" [5]=> string(4) "0.50" [6]=> string(4) "0.00" [7]=> string(4) "0.00" [8]=> string(4) "0.00" [9]=> string(4) "0.00" [10]=> string(4) "0.50" [11]=> string(4) "0.00" [12]=> string(4) "0.00" [13]=> string(4) "0.00" [14]=> string(4) "0.00" [15]=> string(4) "0.00" [16]=> string(4) "0.00" }
```

Code:

```
$corp_resp_template = array();

while ($mostrar = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {

$corp_resp_template[] = $mostrar['corp_resp_template'];
}
```

corp_resp_template Output:

```
array(17) { [0]=> string(4) "0.15" [1]=> string(4) "0.15" [2]=> string(4) "0.15" [3]=> string(4) "0.15" [4]=> string(4) "0.15" [5]=> string(4) "0.15" [6]=> string(4) "0.15" [7]=> string(4) "0.15" [8]=> string(4) "0.15" [9]=> string(4) "0.15" [10]=> string(4) "0.15" [11]=> string(4) "0.15" [12]=> string(4) "0.15" [13]=> string(4) "0.15" [14]=> string(4) "0.15" [15]=> string(4) "0.15" [16]=> string(4) "0.15" }
```

Is giving the following error:  `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:`
Where the 2 are arrays.

Another doubt is how to work when i have corp_resp_template and i want to do the result for diferents corp_resp in the same function?

Comment: How about to do and `var_dump($item);` in the callback, to see what is coming. Tip: Arrays can not added to values ,`+=` will not work with arrays. Also for `*` test also  `var_dump($x);` and `$y`

Comment: And finllay `array_map` has no second parameter like `$carray,$item` for `array_reduce()`. So this will not work.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions is not giving values var_dump of the variables you told me. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: `function($x, $y) { var_dump($x); var_dump($y);  return $x * $y; }`

Comment: `function($carry,$item){var_dump($carry); var_dump($item); return $carry+=$item;}`

Comment: please put a executable php array instead of var_dump output !

Comment: $total = (array_reduce((array_map(function($x, $y) { var_dump($x); var_dump($y); return $x * $y; },
                   $corp_resp, $corp_resp_template)),function($carry,$item){var_dump($carry); var_dump($item); return $carry+=$item;},0));    
                                 OUTPUT ->    array(0) { } string(4) "0.15" 
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in @JustOnUnderMillions

Comment: have a nice day

Comment: ??? @JustOnUnderMillions

Comment: Edit the post with the code. @hassan

Comment: You are just dropping code + output into the comment. Saying not a single word. So have a nice day. SO is not a bunch of merlin's ;-)

Comment: Hello @JustOnUnderMillions, sorry for anything. I do what you request, i change the code like you request and show the function with the output requested. I change on the top adding more code about the functions where is getting that values.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to multiple an array by a string, hence the error. But I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, true. @showdev. I need to transforme in the same format both arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was solved with array_shift function. The format array was diferent in both variables it why was giving that error.